# How much time/money would it take to make a better SharePoint?

Tags: sharepoint

I had discussion with a colleague a while back on what would it take to create a better SharePoint from scratch.

Some of the requirements:

- Document management Workflow management
- Good integration on the desktop (version control as part of OS)
- Rich web UI based on open standards
- Very easy to integrate, and extend

I said it would take me 2 million euro's with a very balanced experienced development team.

What is your take?

Answer (score 1):

[Six to eight weeks](http://www.cznp.com/6to8weeks/index.php).

Answer (score 0):

It's a little difficult to estimate a project of this scale based just on 4 short bullet points, especially when it's not clear what shortcomings in Sharepoint you are trying to overcome, or what features in Sharepoint you can do without.

If you want to replicate all of Sharepoint's functionality and make it even better, 2 million Euros won't even get you started.

Comment: You're right it's not enough to make a good estimation based on just 4 bullet points. But based on my own experience with SharePoint, I'm surprised on why people can be enthusiastic about it. I really think the architecture is flawed in many ways. Programming with/on SP is a lot of trial and error.